# Rejection Issue

Tags: ios, itunes

For my app i got rejection detail from apple but I can't understand what to do because I haven't used icloud and apple says you have to please describe me what i should do next. The apple write up is below.

> 2.23 We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is required per the App Store Review Guidelines. In
> particular, we found that on launch and/or content download, your app
> stores 32MB. To check how much data your app is storing:
>
> - Install and launch your app
> - Go to Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage
> - If necessary, tap "Show all apps"
> - Check your app's storage The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g.,
>   documents, new files, edits, etc., should be backed up by iCloud.
>
> Temporary files used by your app should only be stored in the /tmp
> directory; please remember to delete the files stored in this location
> when the user exits the app. Data that can be recreated but must
> persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers
> expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the
> "do not back up" attribute. For NSURL objects, add the
> NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding
> file from being backed up. For CFURLRef objects, use the corresponding
> kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute.  For more information, please
> see Technical Q&A 1719: How do I prevent files from being backed up to
> iCloud and iTunes?.
>
> It is necessary to revise your app to meet the
> requirements of the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. For discrete
> code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer
> Technical Support. Please be sure to:
>
> - include the complete details of your rejection issues
> - prepare any symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, and steps to reproduce the issues for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
> For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log, please see
> Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS Application
> Crash Reports. If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please
> try testing the workflow as described in
> [Testing Workflow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1764/)
> with Xcode's Archive feature.

Comment: Anything you put in the documents directory will be auto backed up by iCloud starting in iOS 5.1 unless you explicitly disable this behavior.  This has been stated before in numerous other questions on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set "do not backup" attribute to let iphone manage all your resources downloaded in document directory.

Place below code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of appdelegate -

```
NSArray *docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentDir = [docPath objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *pathurl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentDir];

const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
    const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
    u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

    int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
    return result == 0;
```

Comment: You do not "have to" set "do not backup". It may be better to store the data in a different folder such as the Caches directory. The use of "do not backup" is only one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

It clearly point outs that your app is storing 32MB of data on launch or content download in Documents Directory. Any data in Document directory is backed up automatically.

So if you want to use the app same way you can do following two things.

1) Store your data in any other directory like "Temp"

OR

2)Mark your data as "do not back up" attribute. For that if you downloading any data from URL,For NSURL objects, add the NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up